# Limit of an integrable function on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if f is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, then $\int_0^1f=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{k}{n})$.

I know that the right side is a particular partition (one where all the intervals have the same length). Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, for any partition $P$, $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon$. I also know that since f in integrable $\sup\{L(P,f)\}=\int_0^1f=\inf\{U(P,f)\}$.

It's clear that I can get finer partitions every time. The problem is that I'm not sure how to get the limit part.

I think the idea is clear, but I'm having trouble writing the formal proof.

Comment: You're almost done.  You want the norm of the net to approach zero.  Since the partition is uniform, the norm of the net is $\frac 1n$.

Comment: I still don't see it. I guess by net you mean the length of the subintervals. So since the norm of the net is $\frac{1}{n}$, when we take the limit, it goes to cero. I'm not sure how to write it.

Comment: Write $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n)$

Comment: Oh, now I think it is clear. I just needed to write down the definition of limit. For every $\epsilon$ there is a $N$ such that $|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{k}{n})-\int_0^1f|<\epsilon$